# My neural network forgets the last training when I try to teach next set of training inputs

Tags: neural-network

Im learning(started today) neural networks and could finish a 2x2x1 network(forward data feeding and backward error propagated) that can learn AND operation for one set of inputs. It also dodges any local minimums using randomized parameters. My first source for this is: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14342/Designing-And-Implementing-A-Neural-Network-Librar

The problem is: it learns 0 AND 0 using inputs (0,0) but when I give  (0,1) it forgets 0 AND 0 then learns 0 AND 1. Is this a general newbie bug?

What I tried:

```
loop for 10000 times
learn 0 and 0
end loop

loop for 10000 times
learn 0 and 1 (forgets 0 and 0)
end loop

loop for 10000 times
learn 1 and 0 (forgets 0 and 1)
end loop

loop for 10000 times
learn 1 and 1 (forgets 1 and 0)
end loop 

only one set is learned 

fail
```

Trial 2:

```
loop for 10000 times
learn 0 and 0
learn 0 and 1
learn 1 and 0
learn 1 and 1
end loop

gives same result for all input combinations.

fail.
```

Activation function for each neuron: hyperbolic tangent

2x2 structure: all-pairs

2x1 structure: all-pairs

Randomized learning rate:   yes, small enough to keep far from explosive iteration (per iteration)

Randomized bias per neuron: yes, between -0.5 and +0.5 (just at start)

Randomized weighting: yes, between -0.5 and +0.5 (just at start)

**Edit:** Bias and weight updates are done for all-pairs of hidden and output layers.

**Edit:** All neurons(hidden+output) use same activation function.

Comment: The second version looks better, however it's impossible to diagnose unless you provide more details about the values of the parameters of the network, and how exactly does the training process look like. Have you tried lowering the learning rate? Did you try to debug the network? The `AND` problem is so simple that you can calculate the expected result with pencil and paper. How do weights behave during learning regarding the expected result?

Comment: Hidden layers biases are going -800 like. But they were supposed to be auto-normalized by the error propagation iterations.

Comment: Weights are smaller than 1.

Comment: It's all about details. You need to provide your complete solution, otherwise it's very hard to guess what's wrong. I can guess all day what's wrong, and shoot ideas like "try to encode outputs with -1 and 1 instead of 0 and 1" and so on, but I don't have the time. And I doubt that anyone will have :)

Comment: What you're describing is a common problem in neural networks called "catastrophic interference" (or "catastrophic forgetting"). The answer below has the solution, but I thought it might help if you had a name for the phenomenon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without specific code it is hard to say for sure, but I think the issue is that you are only giving it one case to learn at a time. You should give it a matrix of your different learning examples, with an expected result vector. Then, when you update your weights and biases, you are finding the values that minimize the error between your network output for all cases, and the expected output for all cases.

For an `AND` gate, your input would be (in MATLAB code, not sure what language you are using but that syntax is easy to understand):

```ml
input = [0, 0;
         0, 1;
         1, 0;
         1, 1];
```

And your expected output would be:

```ml
output = [0;
          0;
          0;
          1];
```

I think what you are doing now is basically finding the weights and biases that minimize the error between the network output and the expected output for just one input case, and then re-training those weights and biases to minimize the error for the second case, then the third, then the fourth. If you put them in arrays like this it should minimize the overall error for all cases. This is just my best guess though without any code to go on.